# Open bootstrap modal from swf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flash

I embedded swf in html5, is it possible to open bootstrap modal from that embedded swf ? Thanks

I already try this, but it's not working.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash.swf" width="150" height="30">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate from the flash file with the html page and call JavaScript functions using

> flash.external.ExternalInterface

Here you can see how [How to Communicate Between Flash and JavaScript](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-communicate-between-flash-and-javascript--active-3370)